# Meta viewport tag to allow responsive site to scale on some screen sizes, but not others

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, viewport, meta-tags

I work on a responsive site with media queries for three screen width ranges:

- 0 - 767 px "mobile" layout
- 768 - 1023 px "tablet" layout
- 1024 px and above "desktop" layout

As with every responsive site, each layout's designed to fit nicely and be legible in the given screen size. So the mobile layout works for screens 320 wide, for example.

At the moment we use the meta viewport tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

which stops the user resizing with pinch-to-zoom and makes the different layouts kick in as you resize your browser.

We would like to change this behaviour to restore the user's ability to scale. More importantly, we want to change the behaviour in the middle ("tablet") range, so we have:

- 0 - 767px - "mobile" layout, as before
- 768 - 1023px - "desktop" (1024px) layout scaled down to fit in the smaller screen width
- 1024 px and above - "desktop" layout, as before

This is so our advertisers who sell 970x250 billboards can be assured their ads will be seen by people who view our site on tablet portrait screens.

Can anyone suggest the correct viewport meta tag for this kind of half-responsive requirement? When I remove the current meta tag the whole "desktop" page layout scales down to fit in my iPad screen OK: but then it does the same on my iPhone, so the responsiveness is lost. On the other hand, with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

as suggested on [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/), the responsiveness is fully on again, so the iPad shows the "tablet" layout.

I've tried deleting my 768 media query with all its CSS, but then I just get the "mobile" layout on tablet from the media query for smaller screens.

Is there any straightforward way to do this? Or do I need to change the viewport meta tag with JS, so the page isn't scaled down on mobiles but is at 768? Unfortunately I can't post the URL of our site, but I'm hoping people will understand this explanation.

Comment: Hm, my colleague advises me the only way to turn viewport scaling on and off is to add or remove the meta tag dynamically. Is he right?

Comment: Thanks Christina, that does seem to be the answer.